# Private photos I'm tagged in on Facebook are not visible to friends when sharing to Everyone

Tags: facebook, photos, sharing

Someone tagged a photo of me on Facebook and there's some privacy settings on that photo where my friends don't see that photo on my profile.

I tried to re-share this photo with privacy set to Everyone but it's still not visible to all my friends.

Is there a way I can set and share this photo for my friends to see?

Answer (score 5):

Whoever tagged you in the photo has their privacy set to only be visable to those who are tagged, NOT the tagged person's friends.  It's a "custom" visability setting.  They'd have to go in and change it to where the checkbox in the privacy setting area next to "friends of those who are tagged" is checked, not unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

## It's all about your privacy settings.

Log in to Facebook. Up on the top right (right beside your name and "Home" is an arrow - click that, then "Privacy Settings".

From here you are editing who sees what on your account.

Next, click on "Edit Settings", which is to the right of "Timeline and Tagging". I think what you're looking for is the fourth one down, titled "Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?" Set it to "Friends", or whoever you want.

There are also a lot of other privacy settings on this page. This page might be useful in learning more about privacy settings on facebook: http://www.facebook.com/about/sharing/

Comment: I did the above mentioned, its still not working for me. Any idea what else can i do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about the owner of that album. He/She, should adjust the setting who can see the photos on his/her album.